# Serving static images with Nest.js

Tags: javascript, static, nestjs

I use ServeStaticModule from '@nestjs/serve-static' to serve static images that located in "static" directory. When i try to access the image on "localhost:5000/image/[image name]" i get this message:
{"statusCode":404,"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Desktop/App/server/dist/static/index.html'"}.
I follow official documentation.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileModule } from './file/file.module';
import { TrackModule } from './track/track.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { resolve } from 'path';

@Module({
imports: [
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
}),
TrackModule,
FileModule,
],
 })
export class AppModule {}
```

How to serve static files like images properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

Set serveStaticOptions: { index: false } is your friend
;-D

```
 // in nest-cli.json
 "sourceRoot": "src",
 "compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "assets": [{ "include": "static/testdata/**/*", "watchAssets": true }]
  }
```

```
 // in app.module.ts
 ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/static/'),
      serveStaticOptions: { index: false },
    }),
```

serves images from src/static/testdata as

http://localhost:8080/testdata/image.png